# Environment to replace \vbox{\hbox{...}\hbox{...}\hbox{...}\hbox{...}...}

Tags: environments, boxes

I am using LaTeX (LuaLaTeX,actually) and lately I found myself doing this a lot:

```
\vbox{%
    \hbox{\strut foo}%
    \hbox{\strut bar}%
    \hbox{\strut baz}%
}
```

I use it inside tabular environments, floats, on title pages and sometimes even in normal text. When I do this `foo`, `bar` and `baz` are always a lot shorter than, e.g. `\linewidth`. I found this to be the easiest and quickest thing to get what I want. On special occasions, when there are a lot of items to display I resort to `\tabular{l}`.

Both constructs look like this is not how LaTeX is supposed to work from an user's perspective. Is there some environment or anything I can use to achieve the same effect as my 5 lines above do? Of course there are for example all the itemizes, but those all have some margin/padding/indent magic about them that always ends up making me want to use Word. My `\vbox`-`\hbox`-`\strut` construct works always as expected, in 100% of my use cases.

Comment: `\halign{\strut#\crcr foo\cr bar\cr baz\cr}` (You can even leave out `\strut`)

Comment: `\def\shortycut#1#2#3{\vbox{%
    \hbox{\strut #1}%
    \hbox{\strut #2}%
    \hbox{\strut #3}%
}` causes an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe some variety of "long" (rows at fixed baselineskip value) stack would suit your needs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{$}
\setstackgap{L}{\normalbaselineskip}
\strutlongstacks{T}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\Longstack[l]{foo$  bar$  baz} & text\\
\hline
\Centerstack[l]{foo$  bar$  baz} & text\\
\hline
\Longunderstack[l]{foo$  bar$  baz} & text\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the first time I come across stackengine. This looks awesome. especially with the long center and longunder variants for tabular environments!

Comment: @user1129682 Thanks.  As it is my package, let me know if you have any questions on its use.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to write your current construct much shorter, use `\halign` (and consider using plain TeX).

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\halign{#\crcr foo\cr bar\cr baz\cr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does `\halign` fall under the category of tex primitives we are not supposed to use (like hbox and vbox)?

Comment: `\halign` is a TeX primitive, but I have never heard that you are not supposed to use any TeX primitives.  It is perfectly safe to use and well documented in the [TeXbook](https://ctan.org/pkg/texbook).

Answer (score 5):

```
\input expl3-generic

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \vboxofhboxes #1
 {
  \vbox:n
   {
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
     {
      \hbox:n { \strut ##1 }
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\vboxofhboxes{
  foo,
  bar,
  baz,
  OK
}

\bye
```

[image]

I can't really see the advantage over

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
foo \\
bar \\
baz
\end{tabular}
```

or similar Plain TeX construction.

Comment: What is this expl3 sorcery? It looks like a lot of libraries to include which will make the build process very time consuming. The advantage would be that `\vboxofhboxes` adds a lot less clutter to my documents and of course I can redefine `\vboxofhboxes` once to add fancy layout everywhere, if I wanted to.

Comment: @user1129682 Time consuming? Not at all, just a couple of seconds, perhaps. On the other hand, it provides for very compact code.